# How do I configure Hibernate Console in Intellij with java config?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

I have a Persistence configured in Java. No `persistence.xml`. Intellij shows me the entityManagerFactory and the entities in the Persistence window. The query runs OK in the application.

How do I get the hibernate console in Intellij to run queries?

I get

```
[2016-09-12 14:09:07] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/Query
```

The dialect is `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect`

The configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "file:${view.config}" })
@ComponentScan({ "my.me.model" })
public class PersistenceConfig {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersistenceConfig.class);

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan("my.me.model");

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return em;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return txManager;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
Properties hibernateProperties() {
    return new Properties() {
        {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
            setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This now works in 2106.3 EAP. The answer is to upgrade.